# Making a list of checkbox components React Native with map()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to make checkbox list component. I am importing Checkbox component from another file and accesing it in my Option function. What is the correct way to map through my Option function and display a list of the Checkbox component? Currently my List is not working i get some errors: Cannot find name 'value'. Property 'disabled' and 'checked' does not exist on type 'Option'.
"Type '{ checked: boolean; key: string; label: string; disabled: any; onPress: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OptionProps'.
Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OptionProps'."

```
type CheckboxListProps = {
    label?: string;
    options: Option[];
    checkedValues: string[];
    onChange: (value: string, checked: boolean) => void;
    disabled?: boolean;
};

export function CheckboxList({ label, options, checkedValues, onChange, disabled, style }: CheckboxListProps) {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {options.map((option) => (
                    <Option
                        checked={option.value === value}
                        key={option.value}
                        label={option.label}
                        disabled={disabled || option.disabled}
                        onPress={() => onChange(option.value, option.checked)}
                    />
                ))}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

type OptionProps = {
    disabled?: boolean;
    label: string;
};

function Option({ label, disabled }: OptionProps) {
    const [checkboxChecked, setCheckboxChecked] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <Checkbox
            onPress={() => {
                setCheckboxChecked((checked) => !checked);
            }}
            label={label}
            checked={checkboxChecked}
            disabled={disabled}
        />
  );
    }
```

app.tsx file

```
export default function App() {
    const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = React.useState("value");

  <CheckboxList
                options={[
                    { label: "label", value: "value" },
                    { label: "label", value: "value2" },
                ]}
                value={checkedValue}
                onChange={setCheckedValue}
            />
```

My checkbox component

```
<Pressable
            style={{ opacity: disabled ? 0.3 : 1 }}
            onPress={onPress}
            disabled={disabled}
            >
            <View style={[styles.box, checked && styles.checked]}>
                {checked ? <Icon name="tick" /> : null}
            </View>
            <Text>{label}</Text>
        </Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have Type clash:

```
type CheckboxListProps = {
    ...
    options: Option[];
};
```

and

```
function Option({ label, disabled }: OptionProps)
```

and

```
<Option/>
```

not going to work together since you define

```
options={[{ label: "label", value: "value" },{ label: "label", value: "value2" },]}
```

In your case you have to rename function Option or Type Option

the quick fix would be:

```
type CheckboxListProps = {
    ...
    options:[{ label: string; value: string }];
    ...
};
```

### update

one more:

```
<Option
   checked={option.value === value}
   key={option.value}
   label={option.label}
   disabled={disabled || option.disabled}
   onPress={() => onChange(option.value, option.checked)}
/>
```

```
type OptionProps = {
    disabled?: boolean;
    label: string;
};
```

type doesn't have checked and onPress
sholud be:

```
type OptionProps = {
    disabled?: boolean;
    label: string;
    checked: boolean;
    onPress: () => void; 
};
```

notice onPress should be `onPress: (e:eTypeHere) => void;`

### update more:

```
onChange: (value: string, checked: boolean) => void;
```

is not going to match:
 `const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = React.useState("value");`
and

```
onPress={() => onChange(option.value, option.checked)}
```

would not work

add

```
type CheckboxListProps = {
   ...
   value: string;
   onChange: (value: string) => void;
   ...
}
```

change

```
<Option onPress={() => onChange(option.value)}/>
```

Comment: hi, still getting the same error after renaming function Option

Comment: Did you rename <Option/> also?

Comment: yes i renamed <Option /> also

Comment: Ok you have now this  "checked={option.value === value}" and you don't have that in OptionProps

Comment: isnt my code functionality/ structure bad? is it then only type problems?

Comment: Your code structure is pretty much React style, the problem you have as that under TS everything should be strongly typed, and it quite a headache specially for beginner, since you will get error every time you forgot to pass prop or type or you have a type clash, but i'm using it for a while and now i don't really have this problems, you just need more practice

Comment: with your update i get following errors - 1. Type '{ options: { label: string; value: string; }[]; value: string; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CheckboxListProps'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CheckboxListProps'.,
2. Cannot find name 'value'.
3. Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'Option'.
4. Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Option'.
5. And in my emulator - Can't find variable value

Comment: Well it should be easier to rewrite then, if you want me to fix this, would be easier if you do a git repo, if you want to fix it yourself then: setState would not accept onChange: (value: string, checked: boolean) => void; so onChange={setCheckedValue} would not work

Comment: @Kikoanno added you one more error